# Will there be an iOS version of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ipad

I saw that QGIS now works on Android, any chance there will be an iOS version?

Answer (score 14):

***Highly unlikely*** even in the event of a sponsor or technical feasibility.

The reason has to do with licensing. The web is filled with articles about [GPLv2 and Apple Appstore compatibility](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/09/the-gpl-the-app-store-and-you/) and even for the cases where they do make it through, there are several examples of [copyleft licensed open source projects that were pulled off the app store](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/01/08/vlc-app-removed-from-app-store/).

Answer (score 4):

A couple of reasons:

1. No one has made a build for that platform.
2. The App Store the GPL are incompatble. QGIS is GPL [Reference](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/is-it-possible-to-have-gpl-software-in-the-mac-app-store) [Reference](http://www.fsf.org/news/2010-05-app-store-compliance)
3. Because of 2. the only way to get an application on iOS without the App Store is via jail breaking which isn't normally what people like to do

QGIS has a lot of copyright holders and the only way to change the licence (not that it should) to something that would allow it in the App Store is getting everyone's permission which I can tell you will not happen.

Answer (score 3):

The iOS build of [Input](https://github.com/lutraconsulting/input) application (based on QGIS libraries) is published on TestFlight, which closes the question of [technical feasibility](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2019/09/10/input-on-ios/) of such solution.

Regardless if the application will be published for AppStore, there exists a solution for [ad-hoc installations](https://wiki.qt.io/Support_for_iOS_and_tvOS) for companies or custom distributions.

disclaimer: I am one of active developers of the application.

---- UPDATE:

[InputApp](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/input/id1478603559?ls=1) is already on AppStore